# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 установка SDK

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sdk, install

Установка Visual Studio 2017 зависает на установке пакетов Windows SDK.

При попытке установить SDK в ручную установка также зависает. (Скриншоты прилагаю)

Подскажите, как это исправить можно ? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а сколько ждали по времени? свободного места хватает?

Comment: ПК оставлял на 8 часов ничего не меняется, места достаточно.

Comment: Попробуйте предварительно установить пакет Windows SDK https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/.

Comment: @frozencoast я же говорил, что пробовал отдельно, на 2 скрине видно, где зависает установка

Comment: Извиняюсь, упустил из виду. В таком случае нужно устранить проблемы, блокирующие установку и удаление - вот официальная утилита, мне помогала, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed

Comment: @frozencoast существуют ли еще какие-либо подобные утилиты ?